# Passport JS session data in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, passport.js

What is the best way to send passport session informations from the back end to the frontend?

My application that works on port 3000. First two gets are for facebook login and redirection. Next one is to get user data from the database (user id should be stored in `req.user`)

routes.js:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : 'http://localhost:8000/',
            failureRedirect : '/fail'
        })
);

app.get('/auth/userdata', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Donator.findById(req.user, function(err, fulluser) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(fulluser);
    })
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.json(false);
    }
};
```

passport config.js

```
'facebookAuth' : {
        'clientID'      : 'secret',
        'clientSecret'  : 'secret',
        'callbackURL'   : 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback'
    },
```

So in my Angular2 application I can go to the `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook`, be redirected to the FB login page and if success redirected to the `http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback` which takes me to the `http://localhost:8000/`.

And in my Angular2 application that works on port 8000

```
getUser(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/userdata')
    .map(res => return res.json())
}
```

Everytime `getUser()` is called, it returns 'false'. Is there a simple and safe way to "inject" this session data to my frontend on the different port? Also when I go `http://localhost:3000/auth/userdata` in browser I can see this profile rendered as JSON.

When I set backend and frontend on the same port It works, facebook, twitter, google, local, everything is fine and `getUser` returns full user profile.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: why don't you serve your angular2 app on port `3000`?

Comment: I'd like to have the frontend end the backend on separate hosts for now.

Comment: I'd suggest to run everything on the same port. You can have two servers on different ports, but proxy one of them to another using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy).

Comment: This may be a Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) issue. Can you check the network tab of the developer console in your web browser? Take a look at the response to the request made by "getUser()", is there an error?

Comment: There is no error. It behaves like a request from completely different place.

Comment: can you solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034310/passport-js-not-working-with-manual-form-data-post-request-angular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a problem with requests in the Angular2. I've added credentials to each request:

```
getUser(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/userdata', {withCredentials: true})
    .map(res => return res.json())
}
```

And now it is fine.

Comment: Hi, I have added also {withCredentials: true} in my request, but get at frist cors problem, but then adding  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'); in the server I get req.isAuthenticated() false. How do you resolve this problem?

Comment: I've got also `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');` in my cors options. And it's working, also for POST request you should include options like `options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true })`